# cloud 9 c9.io remote desktop, gui

Tags: cloud9-ide

I am wondering if there is any solution which can give me a remote desktop (or RD-like) connection to the virtual machine instance I can connect to through the c9.io web interface?

I would like to use this service in a visual way, and the only solution I have currently is to commit plots to a git repo and push the results to github where I can view them in browser.  This creates a time-lag which is undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome Remote Desktop might be a solution if your remote (Cloud9 server) is running Linux.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/8PMxG69VJ6o

For Windows (maybe Mac?):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this, but I don't see a way to enable the chrome plugin from the command line.  I posted a query about this on google's board:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/8PMxG69VJ6o

I have also tried installing ubuntu-dekstop gui:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui

but I ran out of space because it requires ~ 1.7 GB:

$ df
  Size  Used Avail  Use%
  1.5G  979M  376M   73%

I guess I am just running into the limitations of this nice browser-based IDE.

Comment: I think I better understand what you are asking.  From what I can tell, there is no window manager running in the virtual machine instances provided by c9.io.  At most you can get an SSH terminal instance (if you subscribe to the premium service).  This might let you output your results and scp them back to your local machine for more analysis.  However, there is no graphical front end to which to connect as best I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Are the plots in a format that browser can display? if so you can run simple server and view plots with browser.

Comment: I have considered this option.  It would probably work well for simple plots of O(100 kb), and can be facillitated with a git repo and github.  But I would like to visualize some movies (10-100's of plots at O(100 kb)) and I dont think this is a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Xwindows and a vnc server?